# Display for loop values in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one array called `data` I need to display each values of `data array` in a div.This is my function

```
function myFunction(data)
{
    var result = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
    {
        result +='NAME: ' + data[i].name + ', AGE: ' + data[i].age;
        console.log(result)
    }
    $('#info').text(result)
}
```

html:

```
<div id="info" style="width:750px;height:150px;border:1px solid"></div>
```

But its displaying only final name and age from an array.

console.log(result) will return

```
NAME: xxx, AGE: 20
NAME: yyy, AGE: 30
```

I tried like this also

```
result +='NAME: ' + data[i].name + ', AGE: ' + data[i].age;
```

But I couldn't get all datas.

Comment: Instead of $('#info').text(result) try $('#info').append(result) or $('#info').text($('#info').text() + result)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following function:

```
function myFunction(data)
{
    var result = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
    {
        result += 'NAME: ' + data[i].name + ', AGE: ' + data[i].age + '<br/>';
    }
    $('#info').html(result)
}
```

> **Note**: I have used `html` instead of `text` to show next line also.

In your code, you are changing every time text of `#info`, so you are getting only last value always.

---

Another workaround use `append` instead of `text`. Append adds text into where `text` just replace everything:

```
function myFunction(data)
{
    var result = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
    {
        result += 'NAME: ' + data[i].name + ', AGE: ' + data[i].age + '<br/>';
    $('#info').appen(result)
    }
}
```

---

Template string is better way to concatenate string in javascript, like following:

```
result += `NAME: ${data[i].name}, AGE: ${data[i].age} <br/>`;
```

Comment: <br/> is directly printing.New line is not coming

Comment: @krish see updated answer. Use `html()` instead of `text()` to show next line instead of `<br/>.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the whole text value for `#info` with each iteration. You could try:

```
function myFunction(data)
{
    var result;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
    {                
       result +='NAME: ' + data[i].name + ', AGE: ' + data[i].age + '<br/>';
       console.log(result)

    }

    $('#info').html(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/hc3L98wd/

```js
var data = [
  {name:'xxx',age:20},
  {name:'yyy',age:30}
];

var content = "";
$.each(data, function(i){
  content += `Name : ${data[i].name}  Age : ${data[i].age}<br/>`;
});

$('#info').html(content);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="info" style="width:750px;height:150px;border:1px solid"></div>
```

Loop through the data & prepare your content, then add the content to your desired `div` container.

I've used `ES6` template literal.

> Reference :  [JavaScript-Template_literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define `var result="";` outside the for loop. And it is always better to use `.html()` as it allows you to render the HTML tags like `<br/>`. Check the code snippet:

```js
var data = [{name:'jack',age:10},{name:'Tom',age:12},{name:'Mira',age:14}]
function myFunction(data)
{
    var result="";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
    {
        result += 'NAME: ' + data[i].name + ', AGE: ' + data[i].age +"<br/>";
        $('#info').html(result);
    }

}

myFunction(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="info" style="width:750px;height:150px;border:1px solid"></div>
```